# Using the Google Maps (Jquery-UI-Map api), is there a way to attach a close event to an InfoWindow?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, mobile, maps, infowindow

I'm having trouble figuring out how to attach a close event to an `InfoWindow` with the [Jquery-UI-Map api](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/). I'd like to attach a close event within the creation of the `InfoWindow`, or by chaining to the creation of it. Whatever takes the least code and conforms with how the rest of the api is structured.

My current solution is using the google maps api event listeners, it works but I don't like it. I'd prefer a jOuery method.

I currently have:

```
self.snMapElement.gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': infoWindowMarkup},
                          self.selectedStreetMarker);

// Setup close event
google.maps.event.addListener(self.snMapElement.gmap('get', 'iw'), 'closeclick', 
    function() { self.removeSelectedStreetMarker(); }
);
```

I would like to use some method, if possible as:

```
self.snMapElement.gmap('openInfoWindow',
    { 'content': infoWindowMarkup },
    self.selectedStreetMarker).bind('closeclick',
    function(){ self.removeSelectedStreetMarker() }
);
```